# How to override styles on a Lightning component in Lightning App Builder page?

Tags: lightning, lightning-experience, lightning-apps, css

I have created an App Page which has a single component ("[Filtered Tiles by Salesforce Labs](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N3A00000FYEOrUAP)"). The problem I am having with this component is the styling is not quite right:

[image]

The component itself doesn't have a way to control font size or padding or any other CSS attributes. How can I override the CSS in this component so that I can fix the text display issues?

Comment: You are probably using styles which are being used by salesforce themselves. it would be more helpful if you can share the component code

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I don't have the code... it's an AppExchange component. Wondering if there's a way to apply custom CSS or some other solution to controls styles for a component for which I don't have access to the code.

Comment: I see. They expected it to 1 liner report name. They are overlapping image on text. I gues only solution is giving shorter names to reports